# can I get html content in javascript function from a file

Tags: javascript

In a js function I have the following:

```
origin.tooltipster('content', 'html content to display')
```

Is it possible to get the html content from a file?

EDIT: here is the full code

```
$(function() {
    $('.user-hover-card').tooltipster({
        interactive: true,
        content: '<div class="hovercard"></div>',
        contentCloning: false,
        contentAsHTML: true,
        animation: 'fade',
        functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {

            continueTooltip();

            id = $(this).attr('id');
            active = $(this).attr('active');
            var data = { 'userid' : active, 'hovered_id' : id };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/includes/call_files/get_card_info.php",
                data : data,
                success:function(data){

                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    var trophies = obj.trophies;
                    var ranking = obj.ranking;
                    var h2h = obj.h2h;
                    var fairplay = obj.fairplay;



            origin.tooltipster('content', 'html content to display');
                }
            });    
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to have the html content that I want to display to come from another file.

Comment: Is jQuery an option?

Comment: You don't need the bloat of jQuery for this.

Comment: I have edited my post with the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With another ajax request, should be something like :

```
$(function() {
    $('.user-hover-card').tooltipster({
        interactive: true,
        content: '<div class="hovercard"></div>',
        contentCloning: false,
        contentAsHTML: true,
        animation: 'fade',
        functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {

            continueTooltip();

            id = $(this).attr('id');
            active = $(this).attr('active');
            var card_data = { 'userid' : active, 'hovered_id' : id };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/includes/call_files/get_card_info.php",
                data : card_data,
                success:function(data){

                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    var trophies = obj.trophies;
                    var ranking = obj.ranking;
                    var h2h = obj.h2h;
                    var fairplay = obj.fairplay;

                    $.ajax({
                       type: "GET",
                       url: "/includes/call_files/get_card_info_template.html",
                       data : card_data,
                       success:function(html){
                             origin.tooltipster('content', html);
                       }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But you rather should do the job in get_card_info.php if you can

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to clarify what you want to do exactly :

- which file ?
- what does it contains ?
- what do you want to do with ?

If by file you mean "stored on the user's computer", you can't.

If you mean a remote url, you can get the content (as a string) by doing an Ajax request on it.

If you want to parse and access the corresponding DOM nodes, the simpliest is to create a DOM node from it.

Comment: This is much clearer, thanks. Where is the HTML you want to display ? returned by  get_card_info.php, or in another HTML file on your server (which is, I presume, a template file you have to populate with trophies, ranking, h2h and fairplay ?)

Comment: It is in another html file on my server.

Comment: so, either you've got to do another ajax request, or you've got to treat this in get_card_info, as the « success » callback is called on the client